# How to find the pricipal components after perfoming PCA

Tags: statistics, analytics, data-mining

Is there any to find the names of the principal components (attributes) after performing principal components analysis, Mostly PCA tells the minimum number of components 'k' from original 'n' components to classify a given dataset.If possible please provide links to examples in python.I am new to this so if my question is wrong  I am sorry

https://plot.ly/ipython-notebooks/principal-component-analysis/

I am following this example please tell me with this example how i can extract principal components after PCA

Comment: You should provide a reproducible example and you might get some help. What is it that you've done and what don't you understand? If you google "python extract components after PCA" you get many resources - which have you tried and what confused you?

Comment: Thank you i was note able to find that keyword **"python extract components after PCA"** now i think i am getting what I need,I was viewing other examples  of how to do PCA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCA decomposes the covariance matrix into a rotation matrix (eigenvectors) and scaling (eigenvalues).

The eigenvectors are your principal components.

Comment: Thank you please tell me how to get the names (column names in my data set) corresponding to the eigenvectors

Comment: You apparently have not understood PCA. It uses **linear combinations** of potentially *all* columns. It's not selecting single features.

Comment: Thank you,Yes I have not properly understood it, I am searching for an attribute selection method for dataset minimization